# Rediska slow getting keys by pattern

Tags: php, redis, rediska

Method KEYS (on Rediska named getKeysByPattern()) is very slow. 200 iterations on 10k db takes 20-25 seconds!

For example, keys named like `foo:time:*:y:*:m:*:d:*:h:*:i:*:bar_name:*:item_id:*:category_id:*`

Its a normal behaviour of redis or rediska php client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rediska getKeysByPattern uses the redis KEYS command

Here is a bit of text from Redis docs (http://redis.io/commands/keys) regarding that command

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in
>   production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
>   when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
>   for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
>   layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're
>   looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider
>   using sets.